# ajax in coffeescript not working (typesafe-activator reactive-mongo template)

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, coffeescript, typesafe-activator

i have a problem i am banging my head against for a few days. probably something small out of my site.

i'm trying to use the typesafe-reactive stack, starting with the reactive-mongo-coffeescript template and changing it. so, i changed the message div to take customer details, and the backend to get it. i kept the original coffeescript code (maybe that's the problem...).

coffeescript:

```
require(["webjars!knockout.js", 'webjars!jquery.js', "/routes.js", "webjars!bootstrap.js"], (ko) ->

  messagesPerPage = 10

  # Models for the customer page
  class CustomerModel
    constructor:() ->
      self = @

      # the messages field that first name is entered into
      @firstNameField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that middle name is entered into
      @midNameField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that last name is entered into
      @lastNameField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that address line 1 is entered into
      @addressOneField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that address line 2 is entered into
      @addressTwoField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that address line 3 is entered into
      @addressThreeField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that city is entered into
      @cityField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that state is entered into
      @stateField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that zip code is entered into
      @zipField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that country is entered into
      @countryField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that phone is entered into
      @phoneField = ko.observable()

      # the messages field that email is entered into
      @emailField = ko.observable()

      # save a new customer
      @saveCustomer = () ->
        alert("saving")
        data: JSON.stringify({
          firstName: @firstNameField()
          midName: @midNameField()
          lastName: @lastNameField()
          addr1: @addressOneField()
          addr2: @addressTwoField()
          addr3: @addressThreeField()
          city: @cityField()
          state: @stateField()
          zip: @zipField()
          country: @countryField()
          email: @emailField()
          phone: @phoneField()
        })
        alert(data)      
        @ajax(routes.controllers.CustomerController.saveCustomer(), {
          contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(() ->
          alert("done saving")
          $("#addCustomerModal").modal("hide")
          self.firstNameField(null)
        )


  # Models for the messages page
  class MessagesModel
    constructor: () ->
      self = @
      # the list of messages
      @messages = ko.observableArray()

      # the messages field that messages are entered into
      @messageField = ko.observable()

      # the URL to fetch the next page of messages, if one exists
      @nextMessagesUrl = ko.observable()

      # the URL to fetch the previous page of messages, if one exists

      @prevMessagesUrl = ko.observable()
      # save a new message
      @saveMessage = () ->
        @ajax(routes.controllers.MessageController.saveMessage(), {
          data: JSON.stringify({
            message: @messageField()
          })
          contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(() ->
          $("#addMessageModal").modal("hide")
          self.messageField(null)
        )

      # get the messages
      @getMessages = () ->
        @ajax(routes.controllers.MessageController.getMessages(0, messagesPerPage))
          .done((data, status, xhr) ->
            self.loadMessages(data, status, xhr)
          )

      # get the next page of messages
      @nextMessages = () ->
        if @nextMessagesUrl()
          $.ajax({url: @nextMessagesUrl()}).done((data, status, xhr) ->
            self.loadMessages(data, status, xhr)
          )

      # get the previous page of messages
      @prevMessages = () ->
        if @prevMessagesUrl()
          $.ajax({url: @prevMessagesUrl()}).done((data, status, xhr) ->
            self.loadMessages(data, status, xhr)
          )

    # Convenience ajax request function
    ajax: (route, params) ->
      $.ajax($.extend(params, route))

    # Handle the messages response
    loadMessages: (data, status, xhr) ->
      @messages(data)

      # Link handling for paging
      link = xhr.getResponseHeader("Link")
      if link
        next = /.*<([^>]*)>; rel="next".*/.exec(link)
        if next
          @nextMessagesUrl(next[1])
        else
          @nextMessagesUrl(null)
        prev = /.*<([^>]*)>; rel="prev".*/.exec(link)
        if prev
          @prevMessagesUrl(prev[1])
        else
          @prevMessagesUrl(null)
      else
        @nextMessagesUrl(null)
        @prevMessagesUrl(null)

  # Setup
  # model = new MessagesModel
  model = new CustomerModel
  ko.applyBindings(model)
  # Load messages data
  # model.getMessages()

  # Server Sent Events handling
  events = new EventSource(routes.controllers.MainController.events().url)
  events.addEventListener("message", (e) ->
    # Only add the data to the list if we're on the first page
    if model.prevMessagesUrl() == null
      message = JSON.parse(e.data)
      model.messages.unshift(message)
      # Keep messages per page limit
      if model.messages().length > messagesPerPage
        model.messages.pop()
  , false)
)
```

the alert("saving") at the end of saveCustomer pops, so it gets there, and the alert("done saving") in the ajax's done() clause does not, which leads me to believe the problem is in json.stringify.

customer creation div:

```
@* createCustomerDiv Template File *@
@(customer: Option[models.Customer])
  <div class="modal fade" id="addMessageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3>
              @if(customer==None){
            Create
              } else {
            Edit
              }
            Customer</h3>
         </div>


<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
<form role="form">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading collapse in">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      <h3 align="middle"><label>Customer Name</label></h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstNameField">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameField" placeholder="Enter first name" data-bind="value: firstNameField"/>
            <label for="midNameField">Middle Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="midNameField" placeholder="Enter middle name" data-bind="value: midNameField"/>
            <label for="lastNameField">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameField" placeholder="Enter last name" data-bind="value: lastNameField"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      <h3 align="middle"><label>Address</label></h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addressOneField">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressOneField" placeholder="address" data-bind="value: addressOneField"/>
            <label for="addressTwoField">Address (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressTwoField" placeholder="address" data-bind="value: addressTwoField"/>
            <label for="addressThreeField">Address (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressThreeField" placeholder="address" data-bind="value: addressThreeField"/>
            <label for="cityField">city</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cityField" placeholder="city" data-bind="value: cityField"/>
            <label for="stateField">State</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stateField" placeholder="state" data-bind="value: stateField"/>
            <label for="zipField">Zip code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipField" placeholder="zip" data-bind="value: zipField"/>
            <label for="countryField">Country</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryField" placeholder="country" data-bind="value: countryField"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
      <h3 align="middle"><label>Communication</label></h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailField">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailField" placeholder="email" data-bind="value: emailField"/>
            <label for="phoneField">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneField" placeholder="phone" data-bind="value: phoneField"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>



                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: saveCustomer">Add customer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and finally, the handler method. the logger is not logging anything, so i assume the call is not sent here:

```
  /**
   * The customer form.  This is separate from the database customer since the form doesn't have an ID.
   */
  case class CustomerForm(
      firstName: String, 
      midName: Option[String], 
      lastName: String, 
      addr1: String,
      addr2: Option[String],
      addr3: Option[String],
      city: String,
      state: String,
      zip: String, 
      country: String,
      email: String,
      phone: String
      ) {
    val name = Name(firstName, midName, lastName)
    val eml = Email(email)
    val cntry = Country(country)
    val address = Address(BSONObjectID.generate, addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state, zip, cntry)
    val phn = Phone(1,2,3)
    def toCustomer: Customer = Customer(BSONObjectID.generate, name, eml, phn, address)
  }

  implicit val customerFormFormat = Json.format[CustomerForm]

  /** Action to save a message */
  def saveCustomer = Action(parse.json) { req =>
    Logger.debug("saveCustomer called")
    Json.fromJson[CustomerForm](req.body).fold(
      invalid => BadRequest("Bad message form"),
      form => Async {
        CustomerDao.save(form.toCustomer).map(_ => Created)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

any insight will help. thanks.

Comment: Do you get any server or JavaScript errors?

Comment: nothing i can see. silent fail. just nothing happens. the div doesn't even close.

Comment: interestingly enough, if i do this: 
alert("name JSON: " + JSON.stringify({
          firstName: @firstNameField()
          midName: @midNameField()
        }))
it does alert with the right json. but if i externalize it:
dataJson:...
alert(dataJson)
it fails silently, again.